# Pdflatex does not find packages installed with tlmgr

Tags: packages, texlive, tlmgr, tinytex

I installed TinyTeX on Mac OS Mojave. After I compiled some tex file, I got missing package error, though I installed it correctly using "tlmgr" command. I compiled with PDFLaTex and got what follows:

```
macpro$ pdflatex thesis.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (TeX Live 2022/dev) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./thesis.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2021-08-27>
```

...

```
! LaTeX Error: File `setspace.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: ^CX 
! Interruption.
<to be read again> 
                   }
l.28 \usepackage
                {xspace} % Automatically adjusting space after macros^^M
```

here how I check the package is installed:

```
 macpro$ tlmgr search --file "setspace.sty"
setspace:
    texmf-dist/tex/latex/setspace/setspace.sty
```

the "texmf-dist" folder is located here "/Users/macpro/Library/TinyTeX/". I checked manually that the claimed missing sty package is rather present there?

thank you for letting me know what I missed

Comment: you may have two tex's installed, does `which tlmgr` and `which latex`  point to the same directpry?

Comment: /usr/local/bin/tlmgr /usr/local/bin/latex

Comment: if tinytex comes with kpsewhich what does `kpsewhich setspace.sty` show?

Comment: kpsewhich setspace.sty shows nothing

Comment: that's consistent with tex not finding it. I don't have a mac so only other thing I can suggest is running texhash or mktexlsr to update the kpsefiles. That's supposed to be run automatically whenever tlmgr installs a new package but maybe it didn't run for some reason

Comment: According to the Web page, TinyTeX doesn't install anything under `/usr/local`. I believe you also installed TeX via another package manager, possibly MacPorts.

Comment: Did you make sure to run mktexlsr (with sudo if necessary) so the LSR database is updated? tlmge should have done that but...

Comment: running mktexlsr after installing the package worked for me. now I just need to run that command  after running texliveonfly.py to install all missing tex packages automatically. thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as suggested by Herb Schulz, updating LSR database manually fixes the problem (command: sudo mktexlsr). the error didn't show up again for the other missing packages.